# Jquery checkbox checked when i add text value input

Tags: html, jquery, input, checkbox, checked

How can I toggle a checkbox by using a text input check and check automatically if it exists in the list?

For example :

- if you write 222 in the input with `id=222` will be checked
- if already checked it will be unchecked
- if is not found an alert will be shown

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#Scan').on('keypress', function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
      Scan = $('#Scan').val();
      //if value exsit in the list -> checked
      //if value checked -> dechecked
      //if value not exist -> alert not exist
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="Scan" name="Scan" type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Tracking Number" autofocus>
<br/>
<input class="custom-control-input" type="checkbox" id="111" value="111">
<label for="111" class="custom-control-label">111</label>
<br/>
<input class="custom-control-input" type="checkbox" id="222" value="222">
<label for="222" class="custom-control-label">222</label>
<br/>
<input class="custom-control-input" type="checkbox" id="333" value="333">
<label for="333" class="custom-control-label">333</label>
<br/>
<input class="custom-control-input" type="checkbox" id="444" value="444">
<label for="444" class="custom-control-label">444</label>
<br/>
<input class="custom-control-input" type="checkbox" id="555" value="555">
<label for="555" class="custom-control-label">555</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if your result collection has elements in it by using [`.length`](https://api.jquery.com/length/).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#Scan').on('keypress', function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
      Scan = $('#Scan').val();
      target = $(`#${Scan}`);
      if (target.length) {
         target.prop('checked', !target.prop('checked'));
      } else {
         alert("Not found");
      }
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="Scan" name="Scan" type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Tracking Number" autofocus>
<br/>
<input class="custom-control-input" type="checkbox" id="111" value="111">
<label for="111" class="custom-control-label">111</label>
<br/>
<input class="custom-control-input" type="checkbox" id="222" value="222">
<label for="222" class="custom-control-label">222</label>
<br/>
<input class="custom-control-input" type="checkbox" id="333" value="333">
<label for="333" class="custom-control-label">333</label>
<br/>
<input class="custom-control-input" type="checkbox" id="444" value="444">
<label for="444" class="custom-control-label">444</label>
<br/>
<input class="custom-control-input" type="checkbox" id="555" value="555">
<label for="555" class="custom-control-label">555</label>
```

Reference for [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Expression_interpolation), just in case.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use jQuery, but if you insist:

```js
$(function(){
const scan = $('#Scan'), cci = $('.custom-control-input');
let scanVal;
scan.on('input', ()=>{
  let scanVal = scan.val(), good;
  cci.each((i, n)=>{
    if(scanVal === $(n).val()){
      n.checked = !n.checked; good = true;
    }
  });
  if(good === undefined && scanVal.length > 2){
    alert('Never use Alert');
  }
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="Scan" name="Scan" type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Tracking Number" autofocus>
<br/>
<input class="custom-control-input" type="checkbox" id="111" value="111">
<label for="111" class="custom-control-label">111</label>
<br/>
<input class="custom-control-input" type="checkbox" id="222" value="222">
<label for="222" class="custom-control-label">222</label>
<br/>
<input class="custom-control-input" type="checkbox" id="333" value="333">
<label for="333" class="custom-control-label">333</label>
<br/>
<input class="custom-control-input" type="checkbox" id="444" value="444">
<label for="444" class="custom-control-label">444</label>
<br/>
<input class="custom-control-input" type="checkbox" id="555" value="555">
<label for="555" class="custom-control-label">555</label>
```

Comment: This reacts like a radio input group, it never allows you to multiple select choices and type and select/deselect a valid id input checkbox. If i'm following the question right?

Comment: @joshmoto, I've updated my post to reflect what you're saying, but I still don't know what OP wants.

Comment: Yeah it is a strange scenario

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using your conditions specified in question.

My alert is not a true js alert as that will halt any further input changes, so i've created an alert function to show if `[name="scan"]` input value exists in your `checkbox` input ids.

See comments in my script...

```js
// create input ids array
let input_ids = [];

// for each checkbox type input id
$('[type="checkbox"]').each(function() {

  // get the input id
  let input_id = $(this).attr('id');

  // add input id to input ids array
  input_ids.push(input_id);

});

// on input change in doc for elem [name="scan"]
$(document).on('input', '[name="scan"]', function(e) {

  // [name="scan"] current input val
  let val = e.target.value;

  // if val exist in input ids array
  if ($.inArray(val, input_ids) >= 0) {

    // get this input by id
    let $input = $('#' + e.target.value);

    // if input is checked
    if ($input.prop('checked')) {

      // uncheck input
      $input.prop('checked', false);

    } else {

      // else check input
      $input.prop('checked', true);

    }

  } else {

    // run alert
    alert(e);

  }

  // stop propagation
  e.stopPropagation();

});

// not found alert
function alert(e) {

  // activate alert class
  $('.alert').addClass('active');

  // time out to hide
  setTimeout(function() {

    // remove class
    $('.alert').removeClass('active');

  }, 1000);

}
```

```css
.alert {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  background: red;
  padding: .25rem .5rem;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all .5s ease;
  color: #fff;
}

.alert.active {
  opacity: 1
}
```

```html
<input name="scan" type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Tracking Number" autofocus />
<br />
<input class="custom-control-input" type="checkbox" id="111" />
<label for="111" class="custom-control-label">111</label>
<br />
<input class="custom-control-input" type="checkbox" id="222" />
<label for="222" class="custom-control-label">222</label>
<br />
<input class="custom-control-input" type="checkbox" id="333" />
<label for="333" class="custom-control-label">333</label>
<br />
<input class="custom-control-input" type="checkbox" id="444" />
<label for="444" class="custom-control-label">444</label>
<br />
<input class="custom-control-input" type="checkbox" id="555" />
<label for="555" class="custom-control-label">555</label>

<div class="alert">Not found</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```